# How to finalize nested Observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Please, take a look at the following try for better understanding:

```
this.loading = true;
obs.pipe(
   finalize(() => this.loading = false) //If set to false here and the person has children then there will be another request and the requests are not over yet
).subscribe(person => {
    if(person && person.children){
       obs2.pipe(
          finalize(() => this.loading = false) //If only set to false here and the person has no children then the false property will never actually be set to false
       ).subscribe(children => {
          //Do stuff with response
       })
    }
})
```

My goal is to set the `loading` property to `false` just at the end of the request or requests if that is the case.

I hope to have explained my problem well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You generally avoid subscribing inside a subscribe callback. Instead, you combine the observables into a single one, subscribe once, and finalize once. If you explained what you want to achieve more precisely (what is obs1, what is obs2, etc., we could give an example.

Comment: @JBNizet My goal is to request children data (obs2) if the person has children (obs1)

Comment: @JBNizet Basicly the second request/obs2 is only fired based on data from the first request/obs1. That is why the observables are nested

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator to combine the two observables into one:

```
this.loading = true;
loadParent().pipe(
  switchMap(parent => {
    if (person.children) {
      return loadChildrenOf(parent).pipe(
        map(children => ({ parent, children })
      )
    } else {
      return of({parent, children: [] })
    }
  }),
  finalize(() => this.loading = false)
).subscribe(({ parent, children }) => {
  // Do stuff with the parent and its children
});
```